# Trigger with two IF blocks

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Hello I have a problem with my trigger when I use everything alone it works but together no. How can fix the Syntax error?

```
CREATE TRIGGER `C_edit` AFTER UPDATE ON `client`
 FOR EACH ROW 
 IF OLD.name != NEW.name THEN
INSERT INTO `change`(`id_user`, `table`, `column`, `id`, `status`, `before`, `now`) VALUES (OLD.id_user_edit, 'client', 'name', OLD.id_client, '4', OLD.name, NEW.name);
END IF;
IF OLD.name_sql != NEW.name_sql THEN
INSERT INTO `change`(`id_user`, `table`, `column`, `id`, `status`, `before`, `now`) VALUES (OLD.id_user_edit, 'client', 'name_sql', OLD.id_client, '4', OLD.name_sql, NEW.name_sql);
END IF;
error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using multiple statements within the trigger's body, you need to use MySQL's [begin ... end compound statement syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/begin-end.html), along with the `delimiter` statement to change the delimiter:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER `C_edit` AFTER UPDATE ON `client`
 FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN 
        IF OLD.name != NEW.name THEN
            INSERT INTO `change`(`id_user`, `table`, `column`, `id`, `status`, `before`, `now`) VALUES (OLD.id_user_edit, 'client', 'name', OLD.id_client, '4', OLD.name, NEW.name);
        END IF;
        IF OLD.name_sql != NEW.name_sql THEN
            INSERT INTO `change`(`id_user`, `table`, `column`, `id`, `status`, `before`, `now`) VALUES (OLD.id_user_edit, 'client', 'name_sql', OLD.id_client, '4', OLD.name_sql, NEW.name_sql);
        END IF;
    END//
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the BEGIN / END block like below:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `C_edit` AFTER UPDATE ON `client`
  FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
 IF OLD.name != NEW.name THEN
   INSERT INTO `change`(`id_user`, `table`, `column`, `id`, `status`, `before`, `now`) VALUES (OLD.id_user_edit, 'client', 'name', OLD.id_client, '4', OLD.name, NEW.name);
END IF;
IF OLD.name_sql != NEW.name_sql THEN
  INSERT INTO `change`(`id_user`, `table`, `column`, `id`, `status`, `before`, `now`) VALUES (OLD.id_user_edit, 'client', 'name_sql', OLD.id_client, '4', OLD.name_sql, NEW.name_sql);
END IF;
END  $$
DELIMITER;
```

or without the DELIMITER

```
CREATE TRIGGER `C_edit` AFTER UPDATE ON `client`
  FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
 IF OLD.name != NEW.name THEN
   INSERT INTO `change`(`id_user`, `table`, `column`, `id`, `status`, `before`, `now`) VALUES (OLD.id_user_edit, 'client', 'name', OLD.id_client, '4', OLD.name, NEW.name);
END IF;
IF OLD.name_sql != NEW.name_sql THEN
  INSERT INTO `change`(`id_user`, `table`, `column`, `id`, `status`, `before`, `now`) VALUES (OLD.id_user_edit, 'client', 'name_sql', OLD.id_client, '4', OLD.name_sql, NEW.name_sql);
END IF;
END
```

PHPMyAdmin would not require a DELIMITER, whereas MySQL Workbench and others would.

Comment: Because you can configure what delimiter to use on the phpmyadmin gui and phpmyadmin sets and resets the delimiter in the background for you. :)